# Middle li item direct center when items have different widths

Tags: html, css

I have a unordered list, with an logo image in the center list item. Each of the list items either side of the logo are of different widths.

The ul is 100%, with align center applied.

I am trying to find a way that the logo li sits perfectly central to the page, ideally with just CSS.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can achieved?

```
<ul>
    <li>Dummy</li>
    <li>Dummy</li>
    <li>Dummy</li>
    <li><img src="logo.jpg" />
    <li>Dummy</li>
    <li>Dummy</li>
    <li>Dummy</li>  
</ul>
```

This would be how it would output:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it might have been better to give an example with different text lengths in each `LI` ;).

Comment: @JamieBarker See updated.

Comment: Can the HTML be changed?

Comment: @JamieBarker Yes. Its all custom.

Comment: @Paulie_D  This can be done with CSS alone using CSS Exclusions, (check out my answer) however admittedly browser support isn't there yet

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not so hard. Take a look at the css:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 14.285714286%;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is link to a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXmdxb).

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you, but I would like the li's either side of the logo to be their own width up against the logo, not spaced out proportionally. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ccdavies To be honest, no.. Can you make a little drawing?

Comment: I have added an example to the main question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've split it into two separate lists, and moved the image out of the list. 
Floated both sides left and right and applied padding to each side so there is enough gap for the image. Then absolutely position the image to the centre and use the transform *hack* to make sure it's dead centre. You could increase the amount of padding to space the text away from the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/g1dggym7/1/

```css
body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box; /* Make padding be inclusive of width */
}
ul.l {
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:175px; /* Half image width */
}
ul.r {
    padding-left:175px;  /* Half image width */
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:150px; /* Height of the image */
}
section {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
section img {
    width:350px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <ul class="l">
        <li>Dummy</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor Sit</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="r">
        <li>Nar Harbet</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</section>
```

It's worth noting that if the text ends up going onto two lines it looks broken, so you might want some media queries for small screen widths if you don't already.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you can change the HTML (add classes) and you know the width of the logo (assuming 100px for this example).

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="left">Dummy</li>
    <li class="left">Dummy</li>
    <li class="left">Dummy</li>
    <li class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg" />
    <li class="right">Dummy</li>
    <li class="right">Dummy</li>
    <li class="right">Dummy</li>  
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

ul:before, ul:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

ul:after{
   clear:both;
}

li{
   max-width:14.28%;
}

li.left{
   float:left;
}

li.right{
   float:right;
}

li.logo{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-50px;
   width:100px;
}
```

Max-width is 14.28% (1/7th of 100%, because there's 7 items).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with pure CSS, using **[CSS exclusions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-exclusions/)**
however [browser support is very lacking](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-exclusions), only being supported by IE 10+ (!!!)

By setting the following class on the image we can mimic a kind-of float:center effect on the image

```
.exclusion {
  -ms-wrap-flow: both; /* apply exclusion to img */
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0; /* center the img */
  left: 0; /* center the img */
  margin: auto; /* center the img */
}
```

### Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yy31r779/1/) using IE 10+

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.exclusion {
  -ms-wrap-flow: both;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Dummy1</li>
  <li>This is some long dummy2 text!!!</li>
  <li>Dummy3</li>
  <li>
    <img class="exclusion" src="http://placehold.it/300x100" />
  </li>
  <li>Dummy4</li>
  <li>Dummy5</li>
  <li>Dummy6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In a few years time perhaps, even future versions of FF and Chrome don't support it. :/

Comment: I noted that in my answer ;) but look closely at the caniuse link: Current Chrome status: **In development**

Comment: I know, it's a shame because it's quite useful. Probably one of the first "useful" bits of CSS I've come across that IE are the only ones using. Usually it's everyone **except** IE ;). It's great information, but not helpful _yet_.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't fancy changing any HTML at all, you can use the `nth-child` method.

```css
body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:150px;
}
ul li:nth-child(-n+3) {
    position:relative;
    right:215px;
}
ul li:nth-child(n+5) {
    position:relative;
    left:145px;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Dummy</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolor Sit</li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </li>
    <li>Nar Harbet</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

The caveat of this method is that you need to change the `left` and `right` values if the amount of text changes, and if you add or remove `li`'s then you'll need to change the `nth-child` numberings.

Comment: Nice try but this doesn't exactly work. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/f67wLyhe/)

Comment: @Danield "_The caveat of this method is that you need to change the left and right values if the amount of text changes_". Read the answer next time ;)

Comment: That's a pretty big caveat

Comment: @Danield Every answer has a caveat. If the information that's going to be displayed is just static and will only ever be changed when the planets are aligned then it won't be such a big deal for them. It's neater than my other answer, but more fiddly if changing regularly.